# CABasicAnimation Really fast? or Not really working? for Circular Graphs

Tags: ios, calayer, cashapelayer, caanimation

Hi I am trying to animate a UIBezier / CGPath and it appears to be moving way to fast. I have tried a easing curve it seems to be ignored. 
I am not animating a stroke though I feel I should be ? heres what it looks like.

[image: Starts off Grey this is a separate layer with a highlight layer on top]

[image: Then the track layer is filled in with purple but it doesn't appear to follow the easing curve.]

```
// Perform animation with information.
    -(CABasicAnimation*) percentageChangeAnimation:(CGFloat) percent withLineWidth:(CGFloat) lineWidth andHighlightLayer:(CAShapeLayer*) highlightLayer{
        // Address resize issue
        CGPoint center = [self centerOfGraphWithBounds:self.bounds];
        CGFloat radius =  [self radiusWithCenter:center andLineWidth:lineWidth];

        UIBezierPath* animateBeginValue = [self circularPathWithPercentage:0 andCenter:center andRadius:radius];
        UIBezierPath* animateEndValue = [self circularPathWithPercentage:percent andCenter:center andRadius:radius];

        CABasicAnimation* changeHighlight = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];

        // Property to animate uhh something odd going on... way to fast?
        changeHighlight.duration = 5.0;
        changeHighlight.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

        // begining path
        highlightLayer.path = [animateBeginValue CGPath];

        // CAST
        changeHighlight.fromValue = (id)[animateBeginValue CGPath];
        changeHighlight.toValue = (id)[animateEndValue CGPath];
        changeHighlight.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

        // sync layer with model layer in a TODO
        // Don't remove revert to the model layer from the presentation layer.
        changeHighlight.removedOnCompletion = NO;

        [highlightLayer addAnimation:changeHighlight forKey:@"change"];

        // Id key for the animation
        return changeHighlight;
    }
```

Starts off Grey this is a separate layer with a highlight layer on top
Then the track layer is filled in with purple but it doesn't appear to follow the easing curve

It's almost as if it's ignoring the CATiming as well as the duration.
From my understanding the path can be animated.

Edit solved:

```
// Perform animation with information.
-(CABasicAnimation*) percentageChangeAnimation:(CGFloat) percent withLineWidth:(CGFloat) lineWidth andHighlightLayer:(CAShapeLayer*) highlightLayer{
    // Address resize issue
    CGPoint center = [self centerOfGraphWithBounds:self.bounds];
    CGFloat radius =  [self radiusWithCenter:center andLineWidth:lineWidth];

    /**
    UIBezierPath* animateBeginValue = [self circularPathWithPercentage:0 andCenter:center andRadius:radius];
    UIBezierPath* animateEndValue = [self circularPathWithPercentage:percent andCenter:center andRadius:radius];
    **/


    CABasicAnimation* changeHighlight = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    changeHighlight.duration = 2.0f;
    changeHighlight.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    changeHighlight.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];


    /**
    CABasicAnimation* changeHighlight = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];


    // begining path

    highlightLayer.path = [animateBeginValue CGPath];
    // Property to animate uhh something odd going on...
    changeHighlight.duration = 5.0;
    changeHighlight.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    // CAST
    changeHighlight.fromValue = (id)[animateBeginValue CGPath];
    changeHighlight.toValue = (id)[animateEndValue CGPath];

  **/


    changeHighlight.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    // Don't remove revert to the model layer from the presentation layer.
    changeHighlight.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    highlightLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor flatPurpleColor] CGColor];
    [highlightLayer addAnimation:changeHighlight forKey:@"change"];

    // Id key for the animation
    return changeHighlight;
}
```

now I just have to adjust the calculation for the percentage for the graph. Thanks anyways

Comment: Okay so I solved this issue I am supposed to use the stroke and not calculate the new BezierPathe's.

So what I did instead was use the strokes to animate the path.
Make the highlighted path a clear color but make it the full circle.

Then change the color of the stroke from the highlight path on animation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution above, you need to use stroke path end and start.